# Append two address html fields in a php form

Tags: php, forms

In a form, i would like to have two address fields for the people who have long addresses but i'm not sure how to do that
Here's what my form looks like :

```
<?php
# other..code

if isset($_POST['email']) { 
    $postinfo = http_build_query(
                    array(
                    'lname' => $lname,
                    'fname' => $fname,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'address' => $address,
                    'list' => $list,
                    'boolean' => 'true'
                    )
                );
}
# other..code

 ?>
<div><label for="fname">First Name</label><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"/></div>

<div><label for="lname">Last Name</label><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"/></div>

<div><label for="email">Email</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email"/></div>

<div><label for="address">Address</label><input type="text" name="address" id="address"/></div>
```

So what i would like is to have two separate address fields like this :

```
<div><label for="address">Address 1</label><input type="text" name="address" id="address"/></div>

<div><label for="address">Address 2</label><input type="text" name="address" id="address"/></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what a long address is exactly, but I would probably change the address to a `textarea` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an input array like below.

```
<input type="text" name="address['longAddress]" id="address"/>
<input type="text" name="address['shortAddress]" id="address"/>
```

And then access them in php like this.

```
echo $_POST['address']['longAddress'];
echo $_POST['address']['shortAddress'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array, presuming `$address2` is `$_POST['address2']`

```
 array(
      'lname' => $lname,
      'fname' => $fname,
      'email' => $email,
      'address' => $address . (!empty($address2) ? " ".$address2 : ''),
      'list' => $list,
      'boolean' => 'true'
 )
```

HTML:

```
<div><label for="address2">Address 2</label><input type="text" name="address2" id="addres2s"/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible approaches:

- you indeed use two separate fields, in that case you have to use two different (or at least distinguishable) names for the fields, so that their values get transmitted separate of each other:

`<div><label for="address-1">Address 1</label><input type="text" name="address-1" id="address-1"/></div>`

`<div><label for="address">Address 2</label><input type="text" name="address-2" id="address-2"/></div>`

- you use a textarea instead of two separate input fields which certainly is much more flexible:

`<div><label for="address">Address</label><textarea name="address" id="address"></div>`